# Are Rob Thomas the musician and Rob Thomas the show creator the same person?

Tags: veronica-mars, izombie

When I first saw that the shows Veronica Mars and iZombie were created by someone named Rob Thomas I first thought it was someone who coincidentally shared the name as the singer, but having seen Rob Thomas the singer appear on the iZombie second season finale now I'm not so sure- does anyone know for certain if they are one and the same?

Comment: Rob Zombie however, is both a singer and writer/director.

Comment: Do I remember right that in *Veronica Mars* someone says in the background “Rob Thomas [musician] is a whore”?

Answer (score 9):

## No

Rob Thomas (the writer) explained how he got Rob Thomas (the singer)

> Rob Thomas: Rob Thomas and I have been in touch via Twitter for a long time because we get each other’s stuff all the time and we just kind of forward it to the other person. And he’s always been very friendly. In the [writer’s] room we were talking about initially that there should be a Super Max jingle, and could we get Rob Thomas to sing the Super Max jingle just to make things weird?
>
> Thomas: We were in the writer’s room breaking that final episode and one of the big ideas in “iZombie” is that if the zombie eats the brain of a human that you get their attributes, and when we landed on that idea in the writers room that  [a] Fillmore Graves mercenary would be singing Rob Thomas on the way out, it made us so happy. And then it was just finding the right song, and we thought “Unwell” was sort of the perfect song to go out on.
>
> [**Source**](https://www.latimes.com/entertainment/herocomplex/la-et-hc-izombie-20160727-snap-story.html)